# waitForEvent is not finding the DOM change after fireEvent is called

Tags: react-testing-library

I have the following component that I'm trying to test with react-testing-library:

```
const PasswordIconButton = ({
  stateString
}) => {
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(Store);
  const showPassword = getObjectValue(stateString, state);
  const toggleShowPassword = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    dispatch(toggleBoolean(stateString, !showPassword));
  };
  return (
    <Layout
      showPassword={showPassword}
      toggleShowPassword={toggleShowPassword}
    />
  );
};
export default PasswordIconButton;

const Layout = ({
  showPassword,
  toggleShowPassword
}) => {
  return (
    <IconButton onClick={toggleShowPassword} data-testid="iconButton">
      {showPassword ? (
        <HidePasswordIcon data-testid="hidePasswordIcon" />
      ) : (
        <ShowPasswordIcon data-testid="showPasswordIcon" />
      )}
    </IconButton>
  );
};
```

This works exactly as intended in production. If the user clicks the button then it calls `toggleShowPassword()` which toggles the value of boolean const `showPassword`.

If `showPassword` is equal to false and the user clicks the button, I can see that the `<ShowPasswordIcon />` is removed and `<HidePasswordIcon />` appears. Both have the correct `data-testid` attributes set.

I'm attempting to test the component will the following test:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  render,
  cleanup,
  fireEvent,
  waitForElement
} from "react-testing-library";

import PasswordIconButton from "./PasswordIconButton";

afterEach(cleanup);

const mockProps = {
  stateString: "signUpForm.fields.password.showPassword"
};

describe("<PasswordIconButtonIcon />", () => {
  it("renders as snapshot", () => {
    const { asFragment } = render(<PasswordIconButton {...mockProps} />);
    expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  //
  // ISSUE IS WITH THIS TEST:
  // ::::::::::::::::::::::::::

  it("shows 'hide password' icon on first click", async () => {
    const { container, getByTestId } = render(
      <PasswordIconButton {...mockProps} />
    );
    const icon = getByTestId("iconButton");
    fireEvent.click(icon);
    const hidePasswordIconTestId = await waitForElement(
      () => getByTestId("hidePasswordIcon"),
      { container }
    );
    expect(hidePasswordIconTestId).not.toBeNull();
  });
});
```

The `shows 'hide password' icon on first click` test always fails and I'm not sure why. The `mockProps` are definitely correct and work perfectly in production.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... The issue is that I needed to wrap the component in the context provider as `const { state, dispatch } = useContext(Store);` won't work properly without it.

So I changed the render to:

```
    const { container, getByTestId } = render(
      <StateProvider>
        <PasswordIconButton {...mockProps} />
      </StateProvider>
    );`
```

And now the test passes fine.